# How to create a login page in asp.net-mvc using code-first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

This is my situation,I read and tested the tutorial on this page. But the login page is unable to function it just keep on refreshing the page after I clicked on the login button. And i am not sure this is a code-first approach or not.

```
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simple-login-application-using-Asp-Net-mvc/
```

I would like to ask where can i learn the code-first approach on doing login.

Comment: Mentioned tutorial is not code-first, it is a database-first approach.

Comment: Is there any reference for code-first approach?

Comment: Yes, you can go with Microsoft's official docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/

Comment: Also, you can download sample of all the tutorials from end of the page.

Comment: Thanks very much